# Loop with scanner

Tags: java, loops, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write code which will ask me to insert my age. If its under 10, I want it to ask me 3 more times. If its above 10, it will say "welcome". I couldn't manage to do that.

```
package newProject;
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class mainclass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Enter your age");
            Scanner age= new Scanner(System.in);

            int userage= age.nextInt();
            if(userage<10){
                for(int x = 3;x<3;x++){
                    System.out.println(userage+ "is too young");
                    System.out.println("Enter your age");
                    int userage1= age.nextInt();
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("welcome");
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Aside from the serious formatting problems with your code, we need more information than just "it couldn't manage to do that." Please see [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the sense of your program, your error is in the value you set in x variable. You have to set to the x the value of 0 for iterate 3 times.

```
    System.out.println("Enter your age");
    Scanner age= new Scanner(System.in);

    int userage= age.nextInt();
    if(userage<10) {
    // You have to set x to 0 not 3
    for(int x = 0;x<3;x++){
        System.out.println(userage + "is too young");
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        int userage1= age.nextInt();}
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("welcome");
    }
```

Comment: I am only practicing java i learn it by myself today so...
When i write your code,the machine printing the first answer i write, for example if i write 5 then it doesnt matter what i write next it keeps print "5 is too young"

Comment: That's because if you see the first print in your for loop, you use userage variable, but after you read in userage1 variable, if you want to solve this, the second userage should be something like that: userage = age.nextInt(); instead of a new variable userage1. Do you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
for(int x = 3;x<3;x++)
```

You've set the `for` loop to run as long as `x` is less than 3, but you've declared `x` to be equal to 3. Therefore, the condition `x<3` is never met, so the loop is never run. Here's what you should do instead:

```
for (int x=0; x<3; x++)
```

By the way, please use proper indentation to format your code. It is rather difficult to read without indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
package newProject;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        Scanner age= new Scanner(System.in);

        int userage= age.nextInt();
        if(userage<10){
            for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
                System.out.println(userage+ "is too young");
                System.out.println("Enter your age");
                int userage1= age.nextInt();
            }
        }

       else{
            System.out.println("welcome");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really just a repeat of the existing answers.